# Frequency selective preamplifier at 10-20 kHz

Tags: operational-amplifier, signal, receiver, active-filter

I'm looking for a way to amplify microvolt AC signals generated in an induction coil.  I want to use 5 V single supply rail-to-rail opamps to amplify the signal at least 100 times in the range of interest 10-20 kHz, while suppressing noise at other frequencies.

After some background reading I simulated to following design in SPICE.  The first opamp amplifies the signal 100-fold.  Then follows a 2nd-order passive high-pass filter and finally the second opamp which adds another 10x amplification.  The simulation suggests the design will work, but perhaps someone with more expertise can suggest improvements or alternatives.

Before making a PCB and building this circuit I'd like some comments from the community.   Is a similar results possible with only one opamp?  What are sources of electrical noise to consider?

[image]

Comment: Is the induction coil OK to be loaded with 100 ohms (R2) or might you need a higher impedance. Why not add the induction coil's inductance in series with V2? Why are you not considering a sallen key HPF in the output amplifier?

Comment: Is the source of the 10-20 kHz signal generated by your circuitry?  If so, you could use a phase sensitive detector to improve your S/N ratio.

Comment: The source is a non-tuned solenoid coil.  The voltage should be induced according to Faraday's law.

Comment: @Andyaka, I am asking the question in the hopes someone can provide an answer based on experience.  The induction coil is a ~50 turn solenoid 36 gauge wire, diameter 5 mm. Can a Sallen + Key filter be combined with level shifting?

Comment: How flat (how uniform) must your circuit respond to sinusoids over the band of 10,000 to 20,000 Hz? +_1%? +_10%?

Comment: Not so important for me, I mainly want to eliminate noise (both 1/f and high-frequency spikes) at frequencies outside this range.